# reformatting json to look like the following

Tags: python, json

I have the following body of data that I get back from a request I make and will be inserted into my `elasticsearch` database. It currently looks like this.

```
{
    "index": {
        "_index": "menu",
        "_type": "_doc"
    }
}
{
    "input": "burger",
    "output": {
        "category": "Sides",
        "item": "Angus Burger",
        "modifiers": [],
        "quantity": 1
    }
}
```

and I want to parse it so it looks EXACTLY like this

```
{"index": {"_index": "menu", "_type": "_doc"} }
{"input": "burger","output": {"category": "Sides","item":"Angust Burger","modifiers": [],"quantity": 1} }
```

I know there must be a way of using `python` to accomplish this but I am not sure how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Update 1:

After trying the following

```
as_a_string = {
    "index": {
        "_index": "menu_trial_2_no_mods",
        "_type": "_doc"
    }
}
{
    "input": "small mac-n-cheese",
    "output": {
        "category": "Sides",
        "item": "Chick-fil-A Mac-n-Cheese",
        "modifiers": [],
        "quantity": 1
    }
}

val = json.dumps(json.loads(as_a_string))
```

I get the following error.

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Update 2:

It comes out in the following format after doing `json.dumps()`

```
{"index": {"_index": "menu_trial_2_no_mods", "_type": "_doc"}}{"input": "small mac-n-cheese", "output": {"category": "Sides", "item": "Chick-fil-A Mac-n-Che
ese", "modifiers": [], "quantity": 1}}
{"index": {"_index": "menu_trial_2_no_mods", "_type": "_doc"}}
```

But I am looking for this

```
{"index": {"_index": "menu_trial_2_no_mods", "_type": "_doc"} }
{"input": "small mac-n-cheese","output": {"category": "Sides","item":"Chick-fil-A Mac-n-Cheese","modifiers": [],"quantity": 1} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in your question are two hashes, to get as JSON you could first have them in some kind of iterable and then just doing a `json.dump` on each item.

```
data = [
{
    "index": {
        "_index": "menu",
        "_type": "_doc"
    }
},
{
    "input": "burger",
    "output": {
        "category": "Sides",
        "item": "Angus Burger",
        "modifiers": [],
        "quantity": 1
    }
}
]

import json
for datum in data:
    json.dumps(datum)
```

And the result is:

```
{"index": {"_index": "menu", "_type": "_doc"}}
{"input": "burger", "output": {"category": "Sides", "item": "Angus Burger", "modifiers": [], "quantity": 1}}
```

Comment: check my updated answer. I thought you had your data as string, but seeing is a dict() just try with `json.dumps`

Comment: Edited the answer. You have to convert to json each object you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the JSON to python in that way, python only sees that as you assigning one dictionary.

```py
json1 = {
    "index": {
        "_index": "menu_trial_2_no_mods",
        "_type": "_doc"
    }
}

json2 = {
    "input": "small mac-n-cheese",
    "output": {
        "category": "Sides",
        "item": "Chick-fil-A Mac-n-Cheese",
        "modifiers": [],
        "quantity": 1
    }
}
```

Output

```
>> json1
{'index': {'_index': 'menu_trial_2_no_mods', '_type': '_doc'}}

>> json2
{'input': 'small mac-n-cheese',
 'output': {'category': 'Sides',
  'item': 'Chick-fil-A Mac-n-Cheese',
  'modifiers': [],
  'quantity': 1}}
```